# Can/Should AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) be used for a whole commercial website?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I am new to AMP and wonder who it is for.  For instance.

Can or should I create my home page as an AMP page.

I've heard that this is just for news publishers but the acronym states nothing of this, just Accelerated Mobile Pages, pretty general to me.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AMP team member here –

If you're creating a new site that hosts a lot of static content, then the answer is yes – you can, and maybe even should.

If you have an existing site and want an easy way to deploy AMP pages, or if you require a lot of interactivity on your sites, then going all-in on AMP might not be the right approach for the whole site.

I've written about both approaches [on my blog](https://paulbakaus.com/2016/07/01/about-that-mobile-in-accelerated-mobile-pages/) (posts on my blog are all AMP btw, exactly what you've been asking about). It's a great time to think about embracing AMP, now [that Google is bringing AMP to organic search results](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/amp-your-content-preview-of-amped.html).

Comment: Many thanks.  To clarity 'static' content.  is this static as in unlikely to change in the future like a news article or static being 'not dynamic' or not going to evolve over time?  i.e. a web home page may 'evolve' over time to generate better revenue albeit static content (plain html).  How do we handle updates to pages where AMP pages are encouraged to be widely cached?

Comment: I think by static, Paul means a page that is the same for everyone that accesses it. Like a news article, if you and I open the same article, it shouldn't be different. Whereas if you and I opened Facebook's news feed, it would be dynamically populated so it would differ. When I think of static content, the HTML that's stored on the server isn't catered to the user and is what the end user sees. So, you can update AMP pages freely as you need and Google will manually cache the pages or you can ping the servers to cache the updated page.

Comment: Can't seem to edit my last comment, but I meant to say "...Google's crawler will eventually cache the new pages..." now "...Google will manually cache the pages..."

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, AMP is open to anyone and everyone to use. The main difference is that if your canonical page is the AMP page, the `<head>` tag will need to have the `<link rel="amphtml" href="..."/>` in it. Currently, Google search results are only displaying the thunderbolt marker on articles but soon, they will be including other types of webpages.